# using facebook in android application to sign in for a site

Tags: android, facebook

I used `facebook-sdk` to integrate facebook in my android app and now I've succeded to login in fb from it.
My app works with a website.In order to acces that website u need to be logged into facebook.If u are not logged the website will redirect u to login fb page.

What I wanna do is to login from my app to facebook and join the website in the same time.
When I logged into fb I also join the website....no extra things for joinning the site beside login in fb.
Could u tell me how to do that!
Thx.

EDIT:
This the  website is something like this:  when u try to acces it if u are not signed into facebook it askes u to do that.
Once u sign in it display this: http://i56.tinypic.com/2h4m3wk.png
And asks for permissions to acces u private information.Once u give it u have automatically created an account to that website...with all the information from FB.

And what I wanna do is to login from my app to facebook and to automaticaly ask me for these: http://i56.tinypic.com/2h4m3wk.png  and also automatically have an account on the website.Thank u!

Comment: what do you mean by join the website? do you mean join facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pictures you show is facebook asking the user to confirm that they wish to use the app and indicates what the app has permission to do with the users profile. The permissions are set by you the developer in your code, for example when i authorise my app and login into facebook i pass the following string `private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "read_stream","publish_stream", "publish_checkins","user_checkins"};`
This is the list of permissions that will appear when the user logs in for the first time.

You can find a list of permissions and what they are used for [here.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) Hope this helps! If you have not setup and registered your app with facebook then this tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) will help you.

Hope this helps! Kenny

Comment: I've done all this.But the thing is I have something to do and I don't know how could I explain it better to you!PhotoContestOrange is not the name of my app...is actually the website which asks for permission to acces that data from u fb account and use them to create an account there.

Comment: So what I have to do is to create a connection that when I login into my facebook account,the website to ask me for those permissions.I really wish you could help me.Thank u;)

Comment: follow the tutorial i linked. it will show you how to setup your app so you can then use facebook single login.

Comment: I already did that,SSO to facebook but that won't join me too the site too.And I don't know how to do that!!!

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, What site is it you want them to join? If its your own website then you need to figure out how you want to use the data you get from facebook in order to join the user to your site.

Comment: To do that you will to use the app id for that app/site, which is 137299943016525, use that and the permissions it asks for which are email, publish_stream etc... Then when the user has logged in they will be prompted to accept the permissions for that site. I take it your trying to make a mobile app to allow ppl to submit photos for the competition?

Comment: @george let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1582/discussion-between-kenny-and-george)